# error django 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I now get the error below because of this line `setattr(CsvModel, field.value(), CharField())`

**Error: 'dict' object is not callable**

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConfiguratorForm(data=request.POST)
        # Send import to task.
        # Clean all data and add to var data.
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            process_upload.delay(upload_id=upload.id, form=data)
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task
def process_upload(upload_id, form):
    upload = Upload.objects.get(id=upload_id)
    upload.process(form=form)
```

**process**

```
import_this(data=self.filepath, extra_fields=[
                {'value': self.group_id, 'position': 5},
                {'value': self.uploaded_by.id, 'position': 6}], form=form)
```

**model.py**

```
def import_this(form, *args, **kw):
    # make custom ContactCSVModel
    class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):

        for k, v in form:
            setattr(CsvModel, v, CharField())


        group = DjangoModelField(Group)
        contact_owner = DjangoModelField(User)

        class Meta:
            delimiter = ","
            dbModel = Contact
            update = {'keys': ["mobile", "group"]}

    return ContactCSVModel.import_data(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: Sounds like `field` is a string instead. What is `form`?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters updated question with form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second call you are passing in `form.cleaned_data`, which is a *mapping* (a `dict`), so you are looping over the keys, which are strings.

In the first call on the other hand, you are passing in the `form` itself. The second call is thus not the same; the following call would be:

```
form = ConfiguratorForm(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    process_upload(upload_id=upload.id, form=form)
```

The question here is if that is what you actually *meant* to do.

Comment: sorry, I corrected this on my last edit both have delay, sorry for that confusion.

Comment: FWIW Spikes had a PickleError when passing the whole form.

Comment: @Spike: Why are you trying to *call* `form` in your last edit? Remove the `()` from `form`.

Comment: I tried that also tho and got : 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Spike: Are you certain you restarted your server properly to load the code anew?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yes 100% and also restarted celery stuff too. What I have done to make it clear is updated the question with the actual code I have. hoping you can spot something :)

Comment: @Spike: Your code has `for k, v in form`, but that'll fail for a `dict`. Looping over the form should yield only keys.

Comment: I see, form.items() you know what has been confusion me the word 'FORM' I need to change the name! thank you for keeping with my on this. Its been a big help. got it working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case your form argument is a form instance.

In the second your form argument is a dict instance.

Additionnally:

I think your `import_this` method (if it is, indeed, a method of your model) lacks a *self* first argument or should be declared as a `@staticmethod`. It may save you the trouble of calling it with import_this(self.xxx, self.yyy, ...) But I'm not quite sure how you go from upload.process() to a call to import_method() (my Django is a bit rusty).

And for what it's worth I think there are much simpler ways to achieve what you want to achieve (which if I guess well, is load CSV file):

Without form validation: have a look at [csv.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)() will return a dict for each line in your file. Then do:

```
with csv.DictReader(...) as r:
    for line in r:
        instance = MyModel(**line)
        instance.save()
```

With a form to validate data read from the file: do the same but instanciate a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/), which you'll need to define:

```
 with csv.DictReader(...) as r:
     for line in r:
         form = MyModelForm(**line)
         form.save()
```

What you are doing looks like some kind of strange, brain-damaging, meta-programming... Are you trying to create a model on the fly, from what you find in a CSV file ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: So with the dict instance (the one that I get the error with) I need to get the field value, as you can see I loop and get this value which from my knowledge should work i.e. field.value()

Comment: please do yourself a favour and at least learn the very basic things you need to know to do anything with Python and Django. Django forms are documented, and dict is the most used data structure in Python.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers dict however is not working how it should from my understanding, I don't know how to look it up if I don't know what I'm looking for. I'm not asking for hold my hand, I'm only playing this in not a real app. I'm learning a lot from these questions too.